# Saving GIF and items become not clear

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, cc-2014

I'm using Photoshop CC.

I've created a GIF animation with a text, circles etc etc.

This text (and other items) is showing fine in Photoshop, but, when I do "Save for web" and open the GIF, the text become not clear at the end of the animation, like the image above:
[image]

The problem seems to be related to the background color. I mean: on each step of my GIF I've a background (white), just on the last step I removed the background 'cause I don't want it on my animation.
In fact when I add a background color to my last step the result is this:
[image]

So, the question is: how can I correctly create a GIF with transparent background and mantain a good quality?

Thanks

Comment: if your GIF will be on a white background, set the GIF setting `Matte` to white, this will add a better blend with the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIF cannot display semi-transparent pixels. If you want to get rid of the jagged edges choose white as the color in the »Matte« Dropdown-Menu in the Save for Web dialogue.

Radial Gradient without matte color:

[image]

with matte color set as white:

[image]

The Problem with this is, that if the logo is used on any other color than white, it will have a jagged white outline.

[image]

Comment: OP wants an animated .gif so png won't help. Using baked-in white bg is the answer, though.